# Select a dictionary with certain properties of a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Student class as follows :

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMale { get; set; }
}
```

and have list of courses where Students are assigned as a Dictionary, where all courses are stored as:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Student>>
```

where Key (*string*) is the code of the course and the Value (*List< student >*) are the students enrolled to that spesific course with all properties having a value.

Now I want to simplify the data set with only the Name of the students. So I will still have a `Dictionary<string, List<Student>>` where only the `Name` property is set for each and every `Student` object.

How can I write such a LINQ query to fetch the data as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<Student>>>`, you can write

```cs
var newDict = oldDict
    .ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key,
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(s => new Student { Name = s.Name }).ToList()
    );
```

Note that we have a nested LINQ query based on the list of students. It selects all the students of the list and creates new students with only the name set into a new list.

So, for each KeyValuePair, we keep the Key (the course code), but create a new Value as simplified list of students.

---

Instead, you could also create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` with

```cs
var newDict = oldDict
    .ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key,
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
    );
```